# Comma between two clauses

Tags: grammar, commas, clauses

I want to find out why there is no comma between two clauses in this sentence and what is the grammar rule for it.

> But the curious thing was that **while he was doing so** (,) **a
>   totally different memory had clarified itself** in his mind, to the
>   point where he almost felt equal to writing it down.

Comment: Please cite the source.

Comment: The comma is optional there. I'd possibly use a dash in place of the second comma, and retain the first comma because I'd need a pause for breath there if reading. But punctuation isn't grammar (though it is important where different punctuation signals different readings), and it (especially comma usage) is often fairly arbitrary, nowadays tending towards more minimal usage where clarity (including ease of reading!) isn't impaired.